# Titanium facebook module single thread

Tags: facebook, titanium, titanium-modules, titanium-alloy

I implemented facebook login with Titanium(3.1.3) And Alloy.

But sometimes i'v this message Error when i try to login.

`message = "FBSession: should only be used from a single thread";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the SocialIntegrations call you must use your Facebook token after authorize

`Alloy.Globals.Facebook = require('facebook');`

```
    Alloy.Globals.Facebook.addEventListener('login', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        alert('Logged In' + JSON.stringify(e));
        Cloud.SocialIntegrations.externalAccountLogin({
            type : 'facebook',
            token : Alloy.Globals.Facebook.accessToken
        }, function(e) {
            if (e.success) {
                var user = e.users[0];
               // success
            } else {
                //error
            }
        });
    } else if (e.error) {
        alert(e.error);
    } else if (e.cancelled) {
        alert("Canceled");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to answer if you will post code which you use for Facebook integration.

You are probably calling some fb method just after fb.authorize(). Move all queries made to Facebook into event listener:

```
fb.addEventListener('login', function(event) {
  if (e.success) {
    /* your code */
  }
});
```

Also check out those resources from Appcelerator forum:

- [fbsessions should only be used from a single thread - Facebook module 3.1.0](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/151980/fbsessions-should-only-be-used-from-a-single-thread---facebook-module-310)
- [FBSession: Should only be used from a single thread](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154024/fbsession-should-only-be-used-from-a-single-thread)
- [FBSession: should only be used from a single thread titanium error](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154019/fbsession-should-only-be-used-from-a-single-thread-titanium-error)
- [FBSession: should only be used from a single thread](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/154861/fbsession-should-only-be-used-from-a-single-thread)

Comment: Please provide code which is generating this error.  
Did you checked links which I added below?